# Trying to write strings in a file using a class function

Tags: python, function, class

I'm trying to write a simple game and need to write some informations in a file. This is how the code looks like so far:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, password, file):
        with open(file) as inputFile:
            self.playerAndPw = inputFile.read()
        self.name = name
        self.password = password


    def add(self, name, password, file):
        file.write(name + " | " + password)


    def __str__(self):
        print("The player's name is called " + self.name + "\n")

print("Welcome to Guess My Number!")
start = input("Press 1 for New Account, 2 for Log In: ")

if start == "1":
    player = Player
    playerID = input("Enter a name: ")
    playerPassword = input("Enter a password: ")
    fileName = "PlayerAndPassword.txt"
    player.add(playerID, playerPassword, fileName)
```

In the last line there is an exception at the last bracket: "Parameter 'file' unfilled. So the code can't get the information out of the function I'm using in the last line.

Would be great, if someone could help me! Thank you!

Comment: Why are you passing `name`, `password` and `file` as parameters to `Player.add` if you've already passed them to the class constructor?

Comment: Also the line `player = Player` isn't initialising a new instance of `Player`. To do that, you need `player = Player(...)` and pass in the required arguments.

Comment: but you cannot pass the arguments since you have to enter a file. Looks like your design is flawed: you cannot create constructor with a file argument, because that would mean that you never can create a _new_ player. Better use load / save methods, and use json to serialize/unserialize...

Comment: Among the other problems, `fileName` is a string but `add` is expecting a file rather than a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my attempt to correct your code as best I could. As pointed out in the comments, you need to set `player` to an instance of the `Player` class by instantiating it as `player = Player(...)`.

Because you're passing the player's name, password and the file to store credentials in to the `Player` constructor, you don't need to pass these as arguments to `Player.add`, which is why I remove all parameters for that.

I should point out that this implementation is very simple and incomplete, designed only to address your immediate issues. My implementation will result in file handles remaining open after each call to the `Player` constructor. If you opt for this sort of approach, you may want to read [the Python documentation on input and output operations.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, password, fileName):
        self.name = name
        self.password = password
        self.file = open(fileName, mode='a')

    def add(self):
        self.file.write(self.name + " | " + self.password + '\n')

    def __str__(self):
        print("The player's name is called " + self.name + "\n")


print("Welcome to Guess My Number!")
start = input("Press 1 for New Account, 2 for Log In: ")

if start == "1":
    playerId = input("Enter a name: ")
    playerPassword = input("Enter a password: ")
    fileName = "PlayerAndPassword.txt"
    player = Player(playerId, playerPassword, fileName)
    player.add()
```

**Console Output**

```
Welcome to Guess My Number!
Press 1 for New Account, 2 for Log In: 1
Enter a name: Tom
Enter a password: Foo

Welcome to Guess My Number!
Press 1 for New Account, 2 for Log In: 1
Enter a name: Dick
Enter a password: Bar

Welcome to Guess My Number!
Press 1 for New Account, 2 for Log In: 1
Enter a name: Harry
Enter a password: Baz
```

**PlayersAndPasswords.txt**

```
Tom | Foo
Dick | Bar
Harry | Baz
```

Comment: Note that this approach will leave an open file handle and I would personally use JSON here. JSON has the advantage that it already has a serialisation built-in and makes some things much easier (for example player-lookup).

Comment: @MSeifert You're not wrong and I'll add that to my answer as it's a good point. Leaving an open file handle won't affect the correctness of this program though. The intention of my answer was just to resolve OP's most immediate problems.

Comment: @ErikaWorm Glad to have helped, but on Stack Overflow [voting on and accepting answers that solve your problem are preferred over 'thank you' comments.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, password, file):
        self.name = name
        self.password = password
        self.file = open(file, mode='a') #first assign file to self.file(referring to this file)


    def add(self): #need to add those parameters as they are already initialized by constructor 
        self.file.write(self.name + " | " + self.password)


    def __str__(self):
        print("The player's name is called " + self.name + "\n")

print("Welcome to Guess My Number!")
start = input("Press 1 for New Account, 2 for Log In: ")

if start == "1":
    playerID = input("Enter a name: ")
    playerPassword = input("Enter a password: ")
    fileName = "PlayerAndPassword.txt"
    player = Player(playerID, playerPassword, fileName) #create instance with said values
    player.add() #call the add function to add
```

Comment: Yes i did using comments.